# boost::shared_ptr of a class as a struct member

Tags: c++, boost, struct, shared-ptr

I have the following files.

a.h:

```
#ifndef __A__
#define __A__

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>

class A: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>{

public:
 void somefunction();

};


#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

void A::somefunction()
{
    Node new_node;
    new_node.id_ = 1;
    new_node.ptr = shared_from_this();
    C* c = C::GetInstance();
    c->addNode(new_node);
}
```

b.h:

```
#ifndef __B__
#define __B__

#include "a.h"
#include <vector>

typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr;

struct Node{
    size_t id_;
    a_ptr ptr;
};

class C {

public:

    static C *GetInstance(){
        if(m_pInstance == nullptr){
            m_pInstance = new C();
            }
        return m_pInstance;
    }

    void addNode(Node& node);

    void show();
private:

    static C* m_pInstance;
    std::vector<Node> nodes_;
};


#endif
```

b.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"
#include <iostream>

C* C::m_pInstance = nullptr;

void C::addNode(Node& node){

    nodes_.push_back(node);

}

void C::show(){

    for(size_t i=0; i< nodes_.size(); i++){
        if(nodes_[i].ptr != nullptr) 
            std::cout << nodes_[i].id_ << " " << "pointer not null" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main(){

    A a_tmp;
    a_tmp.somefunction();
    C* c_tmp = C::GetInstance();
    c_tmp->show();

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to do is to use a struct to store the pointer of class A instance. But I cannot resolve the relationship between these files. Can someone give me some ideas ?

***UPDATE:***

The problem is, when I compile these files. I got

```
In b.h, error: ‘A’ was not declared in this scope typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr;
```

***UPDATE:***

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'
```

Comment: Looks like code is correct. Do you have compilation errors?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot resolve the relationship between these files" ? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Unick Yes, I got compilation error, which says in b.h : Class A was not declared in this scope.

Comment: Looks like you are missing ; after classes and structs.

Comment: @Slava that is not the reason... But it is a typo

Comment: I think you wanted to include `a.h` in the `a.cpp` file. Am I right?
I know it's not the solution.

Comment: My crystal ball says you have a circular include you're not showing.  We can't know for sure unless you post a [mcve].

Comment: @mtb another typo...sorry

Comment: @MilesBudnek I think this is circular include problem. But I donot have any idea to resolve this...

Comment: Neither do we unless you show us your actual problem.

Comment: @Johnnylin - now, without include guards, you have twice the `a.h`

Comment: If I removed the `#include "a.h"` from the `a.cpp`, the code above compiled with no problems for me.

Comment: @Johnnylin Also, in the `b.h` you need to have `#include <vector>`.
As I said above, for me the code compiled with no errors after removing the `#include "a.h"` from the `a.cpp`.

Comment: Stop!  You are clearly not copy and pasting your actual code into SO.  You are retyping it "in order to show just the relevant bits".  (We know this because your original question had typos that wouldn't have been present in C&P code).  Just showing the relevant bits is very worthwhile (we won't look at a 10,000 line codebase), but the bits you are leaving out are actually the cause of your problem.  What you need to do, is to write actual a.h, b.h, a.cpp files and compile them.  Then when you get the compilation error, copy and paste those files into your question.

Comment: ... assuming that the processing of simplifying hasn't already explained your problem.  (If that happens, edit the question anyway, and then answer it yourself.)

Comment: As @MartinBonner said, if you want to be helped with your problem, put the code that has the compile error in it, because the code after the changes you made till now to the answer is compiling without errors.

Comment: @MartinBonner I am making a minimal example... wait a second.

Comment: @mtb  just updated

Comment: @Johnnylin and the error is still the same?
The error is at compile time?

Offtopic: in the `b.cpp` you need to include `<iostream>` for `std::cout`

Comment: @mtb not the same, it can compile. But when running got the new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A a_tmp;
a_tmp.somefunction();
```

This will not work.  Since `A::someFunction` calls `shared_from_this`, there must exist at least one `shared_ptr` to any `A` object on which you call `someFunction`.  Change this to:

```
boost::shared_ptr<A> a_tmp(boost::make_shared<A>());
a_tmp->someFunction();
```

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks. By the way, in the above example, there is no circular including header file problem ?

Comment: @Johnnylin You have no two header files that include each other, so no.  Circular include issues will usually lead to compilation failures, not runtime errors.